# i want to get "checked" checkboxes using (filter) js

Tags: javascript

i want to get "checked" checkboxes using (filter)

now i get all the checkboxes i want to add filter method to get only checked checkboxes

```js
const infoArr = [];

addARowBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let phNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
  let conName = document.getElementById("contactName").value;
  let arrVals = {
    phNumber,
    conName,
    checked: false,
    elementIndex: null,
  };

  infoArr.push(arrVals);  

 // defining checkboxes
  const checkBox = document.querySelectorAll(".checkBox");
  checkBox.forEach((el, i) => {
      el.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
      console.log(infoArr[i].checked);
      infoArr[i].checked = e.target.checked;
      infoArr[i].elementIndex = i;
   
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a :checked selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked

```js
const infoArr = [];

addARowBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let phNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
  let conName = document.getElementById("contactName").value;
  let arrVals = {
    phNumber,
    conName,
    checked: false,
    elementIndex: null,
  };

  infoArr.push(arrVals);  

 // defining checkboxes
  const checkBox = document.querySelectorAll(".checkBox:checked");
  checkBox.forEach((el, i) => {
      el.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
      console.log(infoArr[i].checked);
      infoArr[i].checked = e.target.checked;
      infoArr[i].elementIndex = i;
   
    });
  });
});
```